# Array entries being overwriten in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I want to convert an integer array to a string array. For example, if `arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`, I want to end up with `arr2[] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}`. This function works fine until it exits the `for` loop where all the array entries are being overwritten with the value of the last entry. Any idea as to why this might be happening?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 5
int main(){
    int nums[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    char **strings = (char **)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(char*));

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        char temp[20];
        sprintf(temp, "%d", nums[i]);
        strings[i] = temp;
        //prints correct values here
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        //prints wrong values here
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
    }

    free(strings);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `temp` is a local variable inside the loop. Each iteration it goes out of scope and its life-time will end. All your pointers will be to this array, so after the loop all your pointers will be invalid. Using it in any way will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Your `temp` is living only one iteration.

Comment: Not to mention that you iterate five times over an array containing only four elements.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah that was a mistake on my part the array is supposed to be {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

Comment: Then please edit your question to fix it. A [mcve] with unrelated errors and problems will distract from the actual problem you ask about.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for bringing my attention to that. It had actually completely slipped my mind, and I honestly do not know why I thought that would work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is `strings[i] = temp;`. This assigns `temp` to `strings[i]`, but then `temp` is a local variable scoped to the loop block, and is not valid after the block terminates.

You'll need to `malloc` memory for each string to hold the copied value (and `free` it when done). `tmp` is also unnecessary since we can `sprintf` directly into the pointer.

`SIZE = 5` but your array only has 4 members, so we have an out of bounds access. I'd prefer to scope this to the data it represents rather than make it a global constant. I'm also assuming this array will handle arbitrary data, because as-is, there's no advantage to it over using `i + 1` inside your loop.

`malloc(12)` is sufficient space to hold a 32-bit int string (`sizeof char` is always 1 and we need space for `'-'` and `'\0'` characters). As pointed out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58771393/array-entries-being-overwriten-in-c#comment103831557_58771672), you can use `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT / 3 + 2`  to compute the correct size for the buffer where `CHAR_BIT` is defined in the `limits.h` header.

As an aside, there's [no need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) to cast `malloc` and it's good practice to use `sizeof(*strings)` in case the pointer type changes during a refactor.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int nums[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int nums_size = 4;
    char **strings = malloc(nums_size * sizeof(*strings));

    for (int i = 0; i < nums_size; i++) {
        strings[i] = malloc(12);
        sprintf(strings[i], "%d", nums[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nums_size; i++) { 
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
        free(strings[i]);
    }

    free(strings);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice, your solution worked best for what I'm trying to do!

Answer (score 2):

Always let the compiler do counting for you.

First, I define below a macro `COUNTOF` that produces the number of *items* (not the number of *bytes*) in the array object; that should be used everywhere.

Second, the `strdup()` library function makes a copy of a string buffer - it counts the length, allocates the right number of bytes, then copies the string into it. Much easier than rolling your own.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define COUNTOF(x)   ( sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]) )

int main(){
    int nums[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    char **strings = malloc(COUNTOF(nums) * sizeof(*strings));

    for(int i = 0; i < COUNTOF(nums); i++){
        char temp[40];  // bigger than any plausible int
        sprintf(temp, "%d", nums[i]);
        strings[i] = strdup(temp);   // HERE
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < COUNTOF(nums); i++){
        //now prints correct value here :-)
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And @ggorlen correctly reminds you to free memory when you're done with it.

Comment: Aside: `char temp[20];` is OK for 32 bit math.  Another is `char temp[sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT/3 +2];` or some other similar self-scaling buffer size.

Comment: Good point; it's 21 bytes to support 64-bit stuff, so there's no harm in just making it 40.

Comment: When I'm looking for quick coding and do not want to compute the buffer need, I think of a likely worst case to support, like int128, and then double it.

Comment: Please note that `strdup` isn't standard C.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually no need to do this in run-time. You can do this at compile time if you can suffer some "X macro" tricks.

```
#define INIT_LIST \
   X(1) \
   X(2) \
   X(3) \
   X(4) \

#define STR(n) #n

#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  #define X(n) n,
    int nums[] = {INIT_LIST};
  #undef X

  #define X(n) STR(n),
    const char* str[] = {INIT_LIST};
  #undef X

  for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof(nums)/sizeof(*nums); i++)
  {
    printf("%d %s\n", nums[i], str[i]);
  }
}
```

Where `INIT_LIST` has to contain all the initializers as integers. After pre-processing, the above expands to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  int nums[] = {1,2,3,4};
  const char* str[] = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};

  for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof(nums)/sizeof(*nums); i++)
  {
    printf("%d %s\n", nums[i], str[i]);
  }
}
```

Performance-wise, this is naturally going to be astronomically faster than any solution using heap allocation. The down side is that X macros can be a bit hard to read.